# How to write custom circe codec for Map[String, Any]

Tags: scala, circe

Is it possible to write custom Decoder for Map[String, Any] using circe? i've found this, but it's only conversion to Json:

```
def mapToJson(map: Map[String, Any]): Json =
    map.mapValues(anyToJson).asJson

  def anyToJson(any: Any): Json = any match {
    case n: Int => n.asJson
    case n: Long => n.asJson
    case n: Double => n.asJson
    case s: String => s.asJson
    case true => true.asJson
    case false => false.asJson
    case null | None => None.asJson
    case list: List[_] => list.map(anyToJson).asJson
    case list: Vector[_] => list.map(anyToJson).asJson
    case Some(any) => anyToJson(any)
    case map: Map[String, Any] => mapToJson(map)
  }
```

Comment: You can do this (manually), but it's almost certainly wrong. You have no guarantee that your runtime type will be any of these, and for a concrete ADT you can always derive both Decoder and Encoder. If you have `Any` anywhere you most likely screwed up your design as you could have something concrete instead and use a specific implementation for this type.

Comment: Unless it's someone else's screwed up implementation that you're forced to use, in which case the original problem still needs solving.

Answer (score 2):

This Circe decoder will convert its Json into `Map[String, Any]`:

```
import io.circe.JavaDecoder._

implicit val objDecoder: Decoder[Any] = {
  case x: HCursor if x.value.isObject =>
    x.value.as[java.util.Map[String, Any]]
  case x: HCursor if x.value.isString =>
    x.value.as[String]
  case x: HCursor if x.value.isBoolean =>
    x.value.as[Boolean]
  case x: HCursor if x.value.isArray =>
    x.value.as[java.util.List[Any]]
  case x: HCursor if x.value.isNumber =>
    x.value.as[Double]
  case x: HCursor if x.value.isNull =>
    x.value.as[Unit]}

import io.circe.parser._

parse("""{"foo": 1, "bar": null, "baz": {"a" : "hi", "b" : true, "dogs" : [{ "name" : "Rover", "age" : 4}, { "name" : "Fido", "age" : 5 }] } }""")
  .getOrElse(Json.Null)
  .as[Map[String, _]]. // <-- this is the call to convert from Circe Json to the Java Map
```

It would be nicer to case match on the cursor value, but those classes are not public.
[image: Circe Json class hierarchy]

Note that I encoded `null` as `Unit`, which isn't quite right -- Scala and `null` don't play nicely and you may need to tailor your implementation to your use case. I actually omit that case entirely from my own implementation because I'm decoding Json that was encoded from Scala instances.

You also need to create a custom `Decoder` in `io.circe` for Java `Map` and `List`. I did the following, which uses package-private Circe code, making it concise but also vulnerable to changes in Circe and forcing you to have your own `io.circe` package.

```
package io.circe

import java.util.{List => JavaList, Map => JavaMap}
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.immutable.{List => ScalaList, Map => ScalaMap}
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.{MapHasAsJava, SeqHasAsJava}

object JavaDecoder {
  implicit final def decodeJavaList[A](implicit decodeA: Decoder[A]): Decoder[JavaList[A]] = new SeqDecoder[A, JavaList](decodeA) {
    final protected def createBuilder(): mutable.Builder[A, JavaList[A]] =
      ScalaList.newBuilder[A].mapResult(_.asJava)
  }

  implicit final def decodeJavaMap[K, V](implicit
    decodeK: KeyDecoder[K],
    decodeV: Decoder[V]
  ): Decoder[JavaMap[K, V]] = new JavaMapDecoder[K, V, JavaMap](decodeK, decodeV) {
    final protected def createBuilder(): mutable.Builder[(K, V), JavaMap[K, V]] =
      ScalaMap.newBuilder[K, V].mapResult(_.asJava)
  }
}
```

```
package io.circe

import scala.collection.{Map => ScalaMap}
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.MapHasAsJava

abstract class JavaMapDecoder[K, V, M[K, V] <: java.util.Map[K, V]](
  decodeK: KeyDecoder[K],
  decodeV: Decoder[V]
) extends Decoder[M[K, V]] {

  private val mapDecoder = new MapDecoder[K, V, ScalaMap](decodeK, decodeV) {
    override protected def createBuilder(): mutable.Builder[(K, V), ScalaMap[K, V]] =
      ScalaMap.newBuilder[K, V]
  }

  override def apply(c: io.circe.HCursor): io.circe.Decoder.Result[M[K,V]] =
    mapDecoder.apply(c).map(_.asJava.asInstanceOf[M[K, V]])
}
```

Fwiw, I'm already thinking of submitting this as a PR to Circe.

Answer (score -1):

```
import io.circe.syntax.EncoderOps
import io.circe.{Encoder, Json}

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
object Person {
  implicit val decoder: io.circe.Decoder[Person] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder
  implicit val encoder: io.circe.Encoder[Person] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveEncoder
}

case class Home(area: Int)
object Home {
  implicit val decoder: io.circe.Decoder[Home] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder
  implicit val encoder: io.circe.Encoder[Home] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveEncoder
}

def jsonPrinter[A](obj: A)(implicit encoder: Encoder[A]): Json =
    obj.asJson

jsonPrinter(Person("Eminem", 30))
jsonPrinter(Home(300))
```

This is done with generics, I hope it helps